# Using Rest based serives in WCF with POST method

Tags: wcf

I have create a Rest based WCF service and it used in a java mobile app is there a way to post values from the java mobile app to my service and i can use it in my application

Comment: Is this question for client or server part?

Comment: i need to use the values posted from the java app in my  server side app

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try setting the method for your function to POST:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "MyFunction", Method = "POST")]
public string MyFunction() 
{
//implementation
}
```